# How to print values in tests?

Tags: substrate

I have following code in decl_module

```
#[weight = 10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(1,1)]
pub fn create_deparment(origin, name: Vec<u8>, location: Vec<u8>, detail: Vec<u8>) -> dispatch::DispatchResult {
    let _who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    let oldcount = DeparmentCount::get();
    debug::info!("Old Deparment Count: {:?}", oldcount);
    // print("Old Deparment Count");
    Ok(())
}
```

This is my test:

```
#[test]
fn create_deparment_test() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        let _result = TemplateModule::create_deparment(Origin::signed(1), "Education".as_bytes().to_vec(), "India".as_bytes().to_vec(), "hashcode".as_bytes().to_vec());
    });
}
```

I want to print the debug::info in terminal while running cargo test.

```
cargo test -- --nocapture
```

Is it possible?

Edit:
println! is working if you test only using template crate, so one can remove the println! while building the substrate runtime.

Answer (score 3):

To use `println!` you've to make sure your test is 'std'.
Something like:

```rust
#[cfg(std)]
mod tests;

// ---

// But some tests are no std
mod tests;
```

---

If you want to use `info!` try `RUST_LOG=info cargo t -- --nocapture`